# Free tool to open swf file with action script code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a free tool to open and recompile a swf file that contains action script 3 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decompileing you will need something like [Sothink](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) 
And for compiling [Flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/)

Hope you're not stealing work ;)

Comment: Thanks! I just want to check the code to send more information to the swf file :) I won't change anything!!

Comment: then you wont have to recompile ^^ 
btw, there are loads of free swf decompilers(just google) but sothink is the best by far, so if you only need it for this, i would use the 30Day trial of sothink

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of various decompilers (some are free, some are paid for but have trial versions). Decompiling a file is not a big deal, there is even a [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashbug/) for this.

However, compiling a code from a decompiler is a really hard task, so do not expect the re-compiled code to work out of the box, you will need to spend a while trying to fix various bugs.